# Unable to get the wrap-file option in meson build system working

Tags: meson-build

I was trying to cross compile glib for arm. It has a dependency on libffi, but found that a meson build for libffi was last updated 2 yrs back and there is a problem with what is available.

Therefore i had to define a wrap file to take the latest source of libffi.

My first idea was to use a wrap file as below -

```
    [wrap-git]
    directory=libffi
    url=https://github.com/libffi/libffi
    revision=head
```

p.s its the head revision that has the right source code for libffi. But it needed a meson revision and doesn't seem to take the head.

Therefore i went for the [wrap-file] option,

```
    [wrap-file]
    directory = libffi-3.3
    source_url = https://github.com/libffi/libffi/releases/download/v3.3/libffi-3.3.tar.gz
    source_filename = libffi-3.3.tar.gz
    source_hash = 72fba7922703ddfa7a028d513ac15a85c8d54c8d67f55fa5a4802885dc652056
```

But still i get this error "Subproject exists but has no meson.build file" when doing a meson build.

This is the original wrap file that came alongwith glib.

```
    [wrap-git]
    directory=libffi
    url=https://github.com/centricular/libffi.git
    revision=meson
```

what is the easiest way to get a wrap file working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far I can see, someone forked project and added support for `meson`, named that branch `meson`, so revision is just a name of branch containing `meson.build`

Official project does not have support for `meson.build`. What is really happening is when you build your project that uses wrap git/file, that project is fetched/downloaded&unzip and it searches for `meson.build` to build that dependency for your project.

You have couple options:

1. Fork project and add support for meson (optionally: make PR to official project)
2. Install and use it as dependency
3. Use `conan` package manager to get your dependency, you can even integrate it with `meson` ([https://conan.io/center/libffi/3.3/?user=*&channel=*](https://conan.io/center/libffi/3.3/?user=_&channel=_))